# How to create a database in MySQL then link it to Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to create a database that I can then read from / write to in Python. I've tried installing the recommended dev installation via this https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html. I then went into the designer and added a table with some entities. However, the UX in MySQL is really terrible and I can't work out how to actually view the table in the database I've just created and add test values or whatever. I got frustrated and uninstalled MySQL completely because either I downloaded it incorrectly (I selected dev machine but I want to develop and run it on this machine, was that the wrong option?) or it's just terrible to deal with. However, it seems like there are no real alternatives unfortunately and so I would appreciate some help with regards to just setting up a simple database and connecting it to Python so I can perform SQL statements from my Python code. Also, another complication is that my normal Python installation (i.e. the one linked to PATH etc.) is 3.6, but I was forced to install 3.7 when I downloaded MySQL so I'm not really sure how that will work.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql/) helps you

Comment: @kellymandem Unfortunately it seems like that tutorial starts at a point where you already have a functioning database setup and know you're way around MySQL. I don't have a database and I haven't a clue how to use MySQL. I do know a bit of SQL though.

Comment: what operating system are you using

Comment: @kellymandem Windows 10. Also I had a look at the "MYSQL QUICK START" part of the tutorial you linked but I want to create my own database not load someone else's which is structured completely differently. And they still don't show how to actually open the database....

Comment: [this](https://www.osradar.com/install-mysql-windows-10/) shows you how to install on windows 10 and this [one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-basic-mysql-tutorial) will show you how to create your own database and manipulate the data therein

Comment: @kellymandem So you can't view your tables in the MySQL UI?

Comment: if you want view your data in a MySQL UI install [mysql workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) after installing mysql but if am not mistaken it does come with the windows installer for mysql, you just have to select it when installing

Comment: @kellymandem Like I said I installed the default one which includes mysql workbench, but as I mentioned the UX is so awful I can't figure out how to open it, hence this post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187785/discussion-between-kellymandem-and-j-p).